# Firefox claims that the add-on isn't compatible

Tags: firefox, firefox-addon

I'm writing an add-on for Firefox 11, but when I load it I get the message that the add-on isn't compatible with Firefox 11.

Here is my `install.rdf`:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<RDF xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#" xmlns:em="http://www.mozilla.org/2004/em-rdf#">
    <Description about="urn:mozilla:install-manifest">
        <em:id>gnup@gear-network.com</em:id>
        <em:unpack>true</em:unpack>
        <em:name>GNUp</em:name>
        <em:version>1.0</em:version>
        <em:description>bleh bleh bleh</em:description>
        <em:creator>Gear Network</em:creator>
        <em:homepageURL>http://gear-network.com/</em:homepageURL>

        <em:targetApplication>
            <Description>
                <em:id>{ec8030f7-c20a-464f-9b0e-13a3a9e97384}</em:id>
                <em:minVersion>3.0</em:minVersion>
                <em:maxVersion>11.0</em:maxVersion>
            </Description>
        </em:targetApplication>
    </Description>
</RDF>
```

Did anyone already have this problem before?

Comment: A side-note: you should use `11.0.*` as `maxVersion`, to include all minor releases.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a list of all versions usable as `minVersion` or `maxVersion`:

https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/pages/appversions/

The value you provided (`11.0`) is probably too specific. Try using broader version identifier, e.g. `11.*`. This will also include all minor updates in the future.

Comment: These are merely the versions that addons.mozilla.org will accept for extensions uploaded there. Firefox itself doesn't have this restriction - you can use any version number.